# Unclear warnings when enabled -XPrint:typer

Tags: scala, scalac

While trying to clarify implicit conversions in my project I've enabled `-XPrint:typer` compiler option.
As a result I got lot of warnings listed, some of them quite clear but a bunch is not clear at all.
Example of the full warning output for such unclear warning:

```
Warning:scalac: package me.enreach.qa.pages.adserver.adtech {
  import me.enreach.qa.Automation;
  import org.openqa.selenium.{By, WebDriver};
  import scala.util.{Try, Success};
  object AdtechLoginPage extends AnyRef with me.enreach.qa.pages.adserver.adtech.AdtechCommon {
    def <init>(): me.enreach.qa.pages.adserver.adtech.AdtechLoginPage.type = {
      AdtechLoginPage.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val URL: String = "https://console.oneadserver.aol.de/h2/set.do";
    <stable> <accessor> def URL: String = AdtechLoginPage.this.URL;
    private[this] val userName: String = "*******@enreach.me";
    <stable> <accessor> def userName: String = AdtechLoginPage.this.userName;
    private[this] val password: String = "*******";
    <stable> <accessor> def password: String = AdtechLoginPage.this.password;
    def open(implicit driver: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver): org.openqa.selenium.WebElement = {
      AdtechLoginPage.this.go.to(AdtechLoginPage.this.URL)(driver);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.waitUntilVisibleByXPath("//div[@id=\'login-container\']//input[@placeholder=\'Username\']", 5000)(driver)
    };
    def login(implicit driver: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver): org.openqa.selenium.WebElement = {
      AdtechLoginPage.this.textField(AdtechLoginPage.this.xpath("//div[@id=\'login-container\']//input[@placeholder=\'Username\']"))(driver, org.scalactic.source.Position.apply("AdtechLoginPage.scala", "/ssd2/projects/ADMP/src/test/scala/me/enreach/qa/pages/adserver/adtech/AdtechLoginPage.scala", 23)).clear();
      AdtechLoginPage.this.textField(AdtechLoginPage.this.xpath("//div[@id=\'login-container\']//input[@placeholder=\'Username\']"))(driver, org.scalactic.source.Position.apply("AdtechLoginPage.scala", "/ssd2/projects/ADMP/src/test/scala/me/enreach/qa/pages/adserver/adtech/AdtechLoginPage.scala", 24)).value_=(AdtechLoginPage.this.userName);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.click.on(AdtechLoginPage.this.xpath("//input[@type=\'submit\']"))(driver);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.waitUntilVisibleByXPath("//input[@type=\'password\']", 2000)(driver);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.pause(500);
      driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type=\'password\']")).clear();
      driver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type=\'password\']")).sendKeys(AdtechLoginPage.this.password);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.click.on(AdtechLoginPage.this.xpath("//input[@type=\'submit\']"))(driver);
      AdtechLoginPage.this.waitUntilVisibleByXPath("//div[@class=\'navLogoutIcon\']", 6000)(driver)
    }
  }
}
```

It is completely not clear for me what exactly such warnings mean. Could you advice?